# Updating ATmega16u2

Tags: arduino-uno

I have the UNO Mini Strong from www.diymore.cc.
I am having the issue of keyboard.h not being recognized.
I have been trying to find the firmware mentioned in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2 from here https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/atmegaxxu2 but, page is gone!

Does anyone know where the firmware can be found and should this work on the board I am trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a little research and it looks that the hardware folder was cleared (see [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware)).

The json file made me think that now this is shipped like libraries, so through a dedicated package which gets downloaded later.

Consequently I checked in the installation folder and... there it is!

In the folder `<arduino install dir>\hardware\arduino\avr\firmwares\atmegaxxu2` you will find a lot of hex files (e.g. `Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex`)

I checked on my portable installation of arduino 1.8.5, but it should be there also for installed versions

Comment: Great. I found the file. I'll update later on the outcome. Thank you.

Comment: While I was researching the DFU programming, I found this, https://github.com/NicoHood/HoodLoader2/wiki which I believe is exactly what I need. Check the example for Serial Keyboard. I will not be able to set this up until next week. I'll post an update.